# settings.DATABASES is improperly configured

Tags: django, postgresql, psycopg2

total newbie here, sorry

- Mac OSX 10.8 Python 2.7 (installed with homebrew)

  - PostgreSQL 9.4(installed with homebrew)
  - psycopg2 2.5 (installed with macports)
  - Django 1.0.4 (installed via `python setup.py install`)

I'm using [this tutorial](http://www.djangobook.com/en/2.0/chapter05.html), and after starting `python manage.py shell` I ran

```
>>> from django.db import connection
>>> cursor = connection.cursor()
```

and got the following:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/dummy/base.py", line 15, in complain
    raise ImproperlyConfigured("settings.DATABASES is improperly configured. "
ImproperlyConfigured: settings.DATABASES is improperly configured. Please supply the ENGINE value. Check settings documentation for more details.
```

The DATABASES section of my settings.py file looks like this:

```
DATABASE_ENGINE = 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2'  #postgresql_psycopg2           
DATABASE_NAME = 'mydatabase'                      #mydatabase
DATABASE_USER = 'sarahr6'             # Not used with sqlite3.
DATABASE_PASSWORD = ''         # Not used with sqlite3.
DATABASE_HOST = ''             # Set to empty string for localhost. Not used with sqlite3.
DATABASE_PORT = ''             # Set to empty string for default. Not used with sqlite3.
```

So I can't figure out why it says it's improperly configured?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify [DATABASES](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#databases) dictionary in `settings.py`:

> A dictionary containing the settings for all databases to be used with
>   Django. It is a nested dictionary whose contents maps database aliases
>   to a dictionary containing the options for an individual database.

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
        'NAME': 'mydatabase',
        'USER': 'sarahr6',
        'PASSWORD': '',
        'HOST': '',
        'PORT': ''
    }
}
```